# Jquery Repeating Problem

Tags: jquery

I would like to trade once a function of the change. but for the change, constantly trying to link the exchange function of detecting a change to the previous transactions. As an example, I put alert. As you can see in the alert process is constantly growing. I just clicked in the process being repeated this process to make what can I do?.

Thank you for your attention.

revision of the code running : http://www.smyrnart.com/deeplinking/index.html

My codes;

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/express/jquery.address-1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('a').address(function() {return $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');});
        $.address.change(function(event) {

            var url="";
            if      (event.value=='/index1')    {url = "index1.html"}
            else if (event.value=='/index2')    {url = "index2.html"}

            if (url!==""){
                $.ajax({url : url,success : function(data){$("#content").html(data);}});
            }
        });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a title="" href="#/index1/">index1</a>  |  <a title="" href="#/index2/">index2</a>
<div id="content" style="margin-top:50px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Index1.html

```
<strong>in order;</strong><br/><br/>

index1<br/>
index2<br/>
index1<br/>
index2<br/><br/>

alert: problem repeat
```

Index2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.address.bind('change', function(e) {
//I used as examples only. anything else to do here, but should be resolved in this process of repetition.
    alert('problem')

});
</script>

<div>
$.address.bind('change', function(e) {
    alert('problem')
});
<strong>Go now #index1, at this #index2</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first unbind the previously bound event then bind new event.

Like  `$.address.unbind('change').change(function(event) {...`
instead of just  `$.address.change(function(event) {`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get more and more alerts every time you click a link in [this](http://www.smyrnart.com/deeplinking/index.html) example, is that every time ajax call is finished with a success, the code in a returned script tag is evaluated hence every time you click a link jQuery binds handler to every link it can find on a page.
Since **there can be more than one handler for any event in Javascript** every time you click on a link in example the handler is attached. So if you click 3 times you get 3 alerts, click 15 times and you get 15 alerts (15 click handlers attached to any link on the page).

Comment: I am change http://www.smyrnart.com/deeplinking/index.html maybe you can see problem now.

Comment: I think it's still the same problem. **Every time** I click link "index2" you load some script and the html. You have to be aware that any loaded and evaluated script has effect on DOM (HTML) in whole page (which in this case result in alert() being fired X times where X is number of times you clicked on "index2.html" link). Maybe you should quit this example with "alert" and just give us example of what your code is **really** meant to do.